Pusher "Websocket connection to ... Failed"
I am using Pusher to have a functioning chat for my laravel app. It works in local mode (over http), but when I push to production, it gives me the following error
WebSocket connection to 'wss://ws-%22eu%22...' failed: 

I tried a couple of solutions here but nothing worked.
I have the port 443 open for the VPS.
That's my config/broadcasting.php
<?php

return [
    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),


    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => true,
            ],
        ],

    ],

];

composer has
"pusher/pusher-php-server": "^7.0",

packages.json
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-image-compression": "^2.0.2",
    "firebase": "^10.1.0",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.16.1",
    "pusher-js": "^8.4.0-rc2"
  },

resources/js/broadcasting.js
window._ = require('lodash');


try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) { }

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true,
    forceTLS: true,
    wssPort: 443,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
});

window.Echo.unsubscribeAll = () => {
    Object.keys(window.Echo.connector.channels).forEach(channel => {
        window.Echo.leave(channel);
    });
}



It looks like there is an issue with your connection string.
It should be wss://ws-eu, not wss://ws-%22eu%22. Can you remove the quotes from your env variables.

Yea I think this is a valid solution, problem is the .env doesn't have this anymore but (neither the key in it), but it keeps showing on the string. No amount of cache clearing would fix it...
